# D3 dynamic network slow when adding nodes realtime

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am struggling to work out why my [codepen](https://codepen.io/aa1024/pen/yqgRPy) is slow when I stream the nodes and links real-time.

In the codepen, I have simulated the real-time stuff by having `links1` and `nodes1` array.
I am adding the nodes and links using `forEach` and calling `add_prc` and `add_conn` respectively which internally calls the `refresh` to display the newly added node or link.

please click the `reset` button to start the simulation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Minor change to fix a major issue.

Here's a screenshot which will clearly explain the slowdown of adding the nodes,links (and this was just by the initial reset click, IMAGINE the number of nodes it'd add in real time when the number of nodes would increase):

[image]

To fix this, you'll have to change the node enter selection (which is incorrect now). Here's the new node enter selection:

```
node = node.data(nodes);

var nodeEnter = node.enter().insert("g").attr("class", "node")
   .call(force.drag);

nodeEnter
 .append("image")
 ...

nodeEnter
 .append('text')
 ...
```

Note the difference, I'm not appending `image` and `text` on every call.

Here's the code snippet:

```css
#nodeConsole {
  width: 80%;
  height: 1px;
  font-family: courier new;
  padding: 1px;
  border: 3px solid gray;
  margin-top: 1px;
  overflow: auto;
}

#linkedNodes {
  width: 80%;
  font-family: courier new;
  padding: 10px;
}

#srcNodes {
  width: 40%;
  font-family: courier new;
  padding: 8px;
}

#targetNodes {
  width: 40%;
  font-family: courier new;
  padding: 8px;
}

rect {
  fill: none;
  pointer-events: all;
}

.node {
  fill: #000;
}

.cursor {
  fill: none;
  stroke: brown;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.link {
  stroke: #999;
}
.node text {
  pointer-events: none;
  font: 10px sans-serif;
}

path.link {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #666;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
}
```

```html
    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
    <button id="ref" onclick="refresh()">refresh </button>
    <button id="reset" onclick="reset()">reset </button>
    <script>
    
    

 var links1 = [{"source":"ctfa","target":"tfa"},
 {"source":"cea","target":"tea"},
 {"source":"ctfe","target":"tfe"},
 {"source":"ctee","target":"tee"},
 {"source":"ctfu","target":"tfu"},
 {"source":"cteu","target":"teu"},
 {"source":"rfa","target":"tfa"},
 {"source":"rea","target":"tea"},
 {"source":"rfe","target":"tfe"},
 {"source":"ree","target":"tee"},
 {"source":"rfu","target":"tfu"},
 {"source":"reu","target":"teu"},
 {"source":"r1fa","target":"rfa"},
 {"source":"r1fa","target":"gfa"},
 {"source":"r1fa","target":"ggf"},
 {"source":"r1ea","target":"rea"},
 {"source":"r1ea","target":"gea"},
 {"source":"r1ea","target":"gge"},
 {"source":"r1fe","target":"rfe"},
 {"source":"r1fe","target":"gfe"},
 {"source":"r1fe","target":"ggf"},
 {"source":"r1ee","target":"ree"},
 {"source":"r1ee","target":"gee"},
 {"source":"r1ee","target":"gge"},
 {"source":"r1fu","target":"rfu"},
 {"source":"r1fu","target":"gfu"},
 {"source":"r1fu","target":"ggf"},
 {"source":"r1eu","target":"reu"},
 {"source":"r1eu","target":"geu"},
 {"source":"r1eu","target":"gge"},
 {"source":"hh1fa","target":"ggf"},
 {"source":"hh1ea","target":"gge"},
 {"source":"hh1fe","target":"ggf"},
 {"source":"hh1ee","target":"gge"},
 {"source":"hh1fu","target":"ggf"},
 {"source":"hh1eu","target":"gge"},
 {"source":"dbfa","target":"gfa"},
 {"source":"dbea","target":"gea"},
 {"source":"dbfe","target":"gfe"},
 {"source":"dbee","target":"gee"},
 {"source":"dbfu","target":"gfu"},
 {"source":"dbeu","target":"geu"},
 {"source":"hflse","target":"tee"},
 {"source":"hfnyse","target":"teu"},
 {"source":"hfnse","target":"teu"},
 {"source":"hfret","target":"tfu"},
 {"source":"hfebs","target":"tfe"},
 {"source":"hfint","target":"tfu"},
 {"source":"c1e","target":"ctee"},
 {"source":"c1e","target":"gge"},
 {"source":"c2e","target":"ctee"},
 {"source":"c3e","target":"cteu"},
 {"source":"c4e","target":"cteu"},
 {"source":"c5e","target":"ggf"},
 {"source":"d1e","target":"ctee"},
 {"source":"c1f","target":"ctfe"},
 {"source":"c2f","target":"ctfe"},
 {"source":"c3f","target":"ggf"},
 {"source":"c4f","target":"gge"},
 {"source":"c5f","target":"ctfa"},
 {"source":"d1f","target":"ctfe"}];

var nodes1 = [{"id":"tfa"},
 {"id":"tea"},
 {"id":"tfe"},
 {"id":"tee"},
 {"id":"tfu"},
 {"id":"teu"},
 {"id":"ctfa"},
 {"id":"cea"},
 {"id":"ctfe"},
 {"id":"ctee"},
 {"id":"ctfu"},
 {"id":"cteu"},
 {"id":"rfa"},
 {"id":"rea"},
 {"id":"rfe"},
 {"id":"ree"},
 {"id":"rfu"},
 {"id":"reu"},
 {"id":"r1fa"},
 {"id":"r1ea"},
 {"id":"r1fe"},
 {"id":"r1ee"},
 {"id":"r1fu"},
 {"id":"r1eu"},
 {"id":"hh1fa"},
 {"id":"hh1ea"},
 {"id":"hh1fe"},
 {"id":"hh1ee"},
 {"id":"hh1fu"},
 {"id":"hh1eu"},
 {"id":"dbfa"},
 {"id":"dbea"},
 {"id":"dbfe"},
 {"id":"dbee"},
 {"id":"dbfu"},
 {"id":"dbeu"},
 {"id":"gfa"},
 {"id":"gea"},
 {"id":"gfe"},
 {"id":"gee"},
 {"id":"gfu"},
 {"id":"geu"},
 {"id":"gge"},
 {"id":"ggf"},
 {"id":"hflse"},
 {"id":"hfnyse"},
 {"id":"hfnse"},
 {"id":"hfret"},
 {"id":"hfebs"},
 {"id":"hfint"},
 {"id":"c1e"},
 {"id":"c2e"},
 {"id":"c3e"},
 {"id":"c4e"},
 {"id":"c5e"},
 {"id":"d1e"},
 {"id":"c1f"},
 {"id":"c2f"},
 {"id":"c3f"},
 {"id":"c4f"},
 {"id":"c5f"},
 {"id":"d1f"}];
    //refresh();
    
     function reset() {
        nodes1.forEach(function(d){ add_prc(d)  });
        links1.forEach(function(d){ add_con(d)  });
    }
 
    function add_prc(newNode) {
        //console.log(newNode);
        addNodeCanvas(newNode.id,newNode.grp);
    }

    function add_con(newConnection) {
        //console.log(newConnection);
        addLinkCanvas( newConnection.source,newConnection.target);  
    }

    //setInterval(refresh, 15000);

    function addNodeCanvas(nodeName,g) {
        var node = {        x: 900,    y: 900,        id: nodeName,    grp:g  };
        var n = nodes.push(node);
       // console.log(node);
        refresh();
    }
    
    function addLinkCanvas(idSrc, idTarget) {
        if (idSrc != idTarget) {
            var s = {},        t = {};
            nodes.forEach(function(curNode) {
                if (typeof curNode.id != "undefined") {
                    if (curNode.id == idSrc) {          s = curNode;        }
                    if (curNode.id == idTarget) {          t = curNode;        }
                }
            });

            //console.log( { s,t});
            links.push({     source: s,      target: t    });
        };
        refresh();
    }

  var width = 960,
  height = 500;

var fill = d3.scale.category20();

var links = [{ source:  "FH", target: "TP" }];
var nodes = [
    { id: "FH", x: 100, y: 110 },
    { id: "TP", x: 200, y: 110 },
    { id: "GW", x: 200, y: 110 },
    { id: "DB", x: 100, y: 110 }
  ]

var map = {}
nodes.forEach(function(d,i){
  map[d.id] = i;
})

links.forEach(function(d) {
  d.source = map[d.source];
  d.target = map[d.target];
})

var force = d3.layout
  .force()
  .size([width, height])
  .nodes(nodes) .links(links)
  .linkDistance(50)
  .charge(-50)
  .on("tick", tick);

var svg = d3
  .select("body")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width", width)
  .attr("height", height);

// build the arrow.
var arrows = svg
  .append("svg:defs")
  .selectAll("marker")
  .data(["arrow"]) // Different link/path types can be defined here
  .enter()
  .append("svg:marker") // This section adds in the arrows
  .attr("id", String)
  .attr("viewBox", "0 -5 10 10")
  .attr("refX", 15)
  .attr("refY", -1.5)
  .attr("markerWidth", 6)
  .attr("markerHeight", 6)
  .attr("orient", "auto")
  .append("svg:path")
  .attr("d", "M0,-5L10,0L0,5");


svg
  .append("rect")
  .attr("width", width)
  .attr("height", height);

var nodes = force.nodes(),
  links = force.links(),
  node = svg.selectAll(".node"),
  link = svg.selectAll(".link");


function tick() {
  link.attr("x1", function(d) {
      return d.source.x;
    })
    .attr("y1", function(d) {
      return d.source.y;
    })
    .attr("x2", function(d) {
      return d.target.x;
    })
    .attr("y2", function(d) {
      return d.target.y;
    });

  node.attr("transform", function(d) {
    return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")";
  });
}


 function refresh(){
  
  node = node.data(nodes);
  
  var nodeEnter = node.enter().insert("g")
   .attr("class", "node")
    .call(force.drag);
  
  nodeEnter
    .append("image")
    .attr("xlink:href", "https://github.com/favicon.ico")
    .attr("x", -8)
    .attr("y", -8)
    .attr("width", 16)
    .attr("height", 16);
  nodeEnter
    .append("text")
    .attr("dx", 12)
    .attr("dy", ".35em")
    .text(function(d) {
      return d.id;
    });
  node.exit().remove();

  link = link.data(links);
  link
    .enter()
    .insert("line", ".node")
    .attr("class", "link");
  link.exit().remove();

  force.start();
}


    </script>
```

And here's a [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/shashank2104/upnLq9gh/7/) (I'm a jsfiddle fan).

And I see that you moved from a canvas to SVG. Anyway, hope this helps.

Comment: thanks, @Shashank. I am planning to add a context menu to each node. I figured out that most of the examples are around SVG (i guess it makes more sense) hence planning to get similar thing achieved with SVG which I implemented in Canvas. my next few questions are going to be around the context menu :) . Thanks for helping me out.

Comment: Glad I could help. Sure. I'd be more than happy to help. Yes, SVGs are good but if you're up for suggestions/opinions && if you have more nodes coming in, canvas might be good but anyway, it's good for now. I'll keep a lookout on any questions. Now it's time for Saturday night! Happy coding!

Comment: Thanks. I think the max nodes can go up to 250-300. and I want to add a context menu to each node to be able to get a few operations done, which one do you think I should go for?

Comment: 250-300 nodes can be easily handled by SVGs. If it’d been over a 1000 or so, canvas would be your best bet is what I feel. Yeah add a context menu and we’ll see how it goes.

Comment: Hi @Shashank, if you don't mind, could you please check out my another [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51460885/d3-nodes-not-appearing-while-updating-it-realtime) , I want to settle with this solution.