# D3 SVG transition issue after deleting few nodes

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am facing a weird issue in this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/aa1024/r1tcj0mf/). If I delete few existing nodes and add new nodes later, the transition of nodes doesn't stay the same.

**This scenario is working fine** :

1. run the jsfiddle.
2. click the `reset` button
3. select `ctee` node which is connected to a few other nodes and drag.
4. all the connected nodes should follow the main dragged node.
5. check out the following screenshot, the connected nodes to the `ctee` node are also moving along with `ctee`.

[image: connected nodes moving with the main node]

**This scenario is having a problem** (only difference is we are going to delete a node first and then click `reset` button) :

1. run the jsfiddle.
2. right click the `GW` node and select the option `Stop`.
3. this will remove the node from the screen.
4. now click the `reset` button
5. select `ctee` node which is connected to a few other nodes and drag.
6. Ideally, all the connected nodes should follow the main dragged node but it doesn't work. the connected nodes stay at their original position.

   > 7. check out the following screenshot, the connected nodes to the `ctee` node are **not** moving along with `ctee`.

[image: Connected nodes not moving when the node is dragged]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue looks like that when you delete a node, you're creating a new reference to `links` that is not in sync with your force layout:

```
links = links.filter...
```

To fix this, you can simply add: `force.links(links);` to the line after it to update the force layout's reference.

Updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/r1tcj0mf/16/

Comment: Absolutely brilliant @Steve. I spent hours to figure out this problem :)

Comment: Was this problem clearly evident or you had to spend some time to this figure out? Apologies if I am bothering you.

Comment: It took me about an hour to figure it out, mostly because I suspected some other lines of code. I had run into a similar force-layout syncing issue before, and from that knew that keeping references current could be the issue.